# SQL Indexed View for Hashtags

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, hashtag

Given a source table with an column containing arbitrary text, which contains alphabetic hashtags (#example, #alsoAnExample, #this-is-not-an-example), what is required to create an Indexed View in SQL server which

Hashtag regex definition:

```
/\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*/
```

Desired view example output:

```
PostId     |    Tag
   1           example
   1           alsoAnExample
   2           yetanothertag
```

This would remove the application tier from the responsibility to create entries for a regular table upon insert, and allow for data entry from other sources without knowledge of the tagging.

If this is possible, can it be done in such as way that inserts (the Posts table is insert heavy) will not cause a significant burden as the View Index will need to frequently updated.

Comment: I think you need to look at full-text search or some method of extracting these hash tags. I don't think an indexed view is going to do anything for you here.

Comment: Aaron, why do you say it won't do anything for myself here?  It's similar to doing a full text index, though I don't need ALL the text (which is several orders of magnitude larger). So you're suggesting that I should just do it at the app tier?

Comment: The Indexed Views are created using WITH SCHEMABINDING option, that is the content of the view is stored physically rather than calculated on the fly. If you think about it, it kind of makes sense if you want to have indexes on something. If your source table is insert heavy, the Indexed View will need to be refreshed on each new row in the source table which can lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can have multiple hash tags per row you obviously can't just use a computed column index. Instead, what you conceptually want to have is an indexed view of the base table cross-applied with a table-valued function that computes the hash tags. I would love to have that in SQL Server, but alas indexed views are extremely limited in what they support. Just forget them for your use case (and look up the restrictions in books online to understand why).

Instead, I recommend that you create a separate table to hold the hash tags (of the form (`PostId INT PRIMARY KEY, Tag NVARCHAR(400) PRIMARY KEY, ...` or similar). Maintain that table in the application tier, or using triggers.

You can also maintain the table in a delayed way so that you can do batch updates and do them in the background. That of course means that the app has to tolerate stale data, and it means more development work.

Comment: Good answer, and I think I'll go the trigger route.  I suppose it's off to do some research.

Comment: It is good to know that you can replicate any functionality of indexed views yourself using triggers. The performance will be different for certain, and you lose automatic indexed view matching in enterprise edition. But you can materialize anything you like at all.